# How can I get Ansible to execute multiple commands using with_items?

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to configure [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) to allow connections to port 80 from a list of IP addresses, using Ansible:

```
tasks:
    - name: Allow port 80 HTTP
      action: shell ufw allow from {{item}} to any 80/tcp
      with_items: allowed_ips
```

The list of IP addresses is stored as a hash in a YAML file, in my playbook's `vars/` directory:

```
---
allowed_ips:
  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I'm using `with_items` to pull the IP addresses into the command but when Ansible runs the playbook it concatenates the IP addresses, inserting a space between each IP:

```
ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any 80/tcp
```

`ufw` doesn't accept this syntax, so I'd like to run `ufw` once for each IP address. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible behaves correctly as currently `allowed_ips` is not a list but a single variable. Make the variable a YAML list:

```
---
allowed_ips:
  - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now the action is executed as many times as there is items in the `allowed_ips` list.

Answer (score 5):

Ansible 1.6 has a module to manage `ufw`. http://docs.ansible.com/ufw_module.html It supports lists you are trying to achieve.

```
ufw: rule=allow src={{ item }} port=80 proto=tcp
with_items:
- 10.0.0.0/8
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16
```

Alternatively, you can try https://galaxy.ansible.com which has a couple of ready to use roles for `ufw`, some of those also support lists of IPs.